# Why is the code working as I want only in the debugging mode?

Tags: python, graphics

I have a problem with python code ,I have to create connect4 game only in graphics library and the code is working as I want only in the debugging mode. for ex in this code when I press 1 , it colors 2 circles in the first column instead of 1 circle.
I use visual studio code
I don't know what is the problem
Thanks in advance

```
from graphics import *
import keyboard
win = GraphWin("Connect4",700,700)
win.setBackground("blue")
x , y = 50 , 50
#draw the board
for i in range (7):
    for j in range(7):
        p=Point(x,y)
        cir=Circle(p,47)
        cir.setFill("black")
        cir.draw(win)
        x+=100
    x=50
    y+=100 
def player(color,a,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7):
    y = 650 
    if a==1:
        p=Point(50+((a-1)*100),y-(x1*100))
    elif a==2:
        p=Point(50+((a-1)*100),y-(x2*100))
    elif a==3:
        p=Point(50+((a-1)*100),y-(x3*100))
    elif a==4:
        p=Point(50+((a-1)*100),y-(x4*100))
    elif a==5:
        p=Point(50+((a-1)*100),y-(x5*100))
    elif a==6:
        p=Point(50+((a-1)*100),y-(x6*100))
    elif a==7:
        p=Point(50+((a-1)*100),y-(x7*100))
   
    cir=Circle(p,47)
    cir.setFill(color)
    cir.draw(win)
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7=0,0,0,0,0,0,0
for i in range (7):
    k = keyboard.read_key()
    a = int(k)
    if i%2==0:
        player("red",a,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7)
    else:
        player("yellow",a,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7)
    if a==1:
        x1+=1
    elif a==2:
        x2+=1
    elif a==3:
        x3+=1
    elif a==4:
        x4+=1
    elif a==5:
        x5+=1
    elif a==6:
        x6+=1
    elif a==7:
        x7+=1

   

win.getMouse()
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why your code works in debugging mode, it shouldn't work in any mode so to speak, i think the debug mode locks your screen so you think it's working when it's not working.

let me explain the problem at hand,
you want to use graphics library to render something on screen, so you should call `win.mainloop()` after defining the player function, so that the computer will start drawing on screen.

this will cause the computer to go in an infinite loop, where it is only drawing on screen and won't respond to your input, so the rest of the code won't really work.

you want your computer to do two tasks at a time, drawing and waiting for your input, this can be done by creating a second thread that monitors the user input and applies your logic as follows, you have to wrap your logic in a function that will be executed by the second thead:

```py
def play_game():
    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(7):
        k = keyboard.read_key()
        a = int(k)
        if i % 2 == 0:
            player("red", a, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
        else:
            player("yellow", a, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
        if a == 1:
            x1 += 1
        elif a == 2:
            x2 += 1
        elif a == 3:
            x3 += 1
        elif a == 4:
            x4 += 1
        elif a == 5:
            x5 += 1
        elif a == 6:
            x6 += 1
        elif a == 7:
            x7 += 1

    win.getMouse()

# code that runs the game logic on another thread
import threading
thread = threading.Thread(target=play_game,args=())
thread.start()

# infinite loop that draws on screen
win.mainloop()
```

here, `play_game()` which implements the game logic will be run on another thread and will leave the main thread to keep drawing on your screen (and handle os commands like moving window, resizing, etc..)